# AWS EB Flask app, where can I see the console output?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The logs from the online dashboard include error logs, access logs, etc but do not have a place for console output (the messages I sent to the console with print statements). Where can I see this information? Either through eb CLI or online dashboard... Thanks.

Comment: Which server are you using ?

Comment: Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.3